# container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused exec: flask: executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, pip, alpine-linux

I am getting error in docker:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
Removing policyclassification_web_1
Recreating 9c6607f3968d_policyclassification_web_1 ... error

ERROR: for 9c6607f3968d_policyclassification_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"flask\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"flask\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

My dockerfile:

[image: Dockerfile]

**Docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5122:5122"
```

**Requirement.txt:**

Cython==0.29.17
Flask==0.0.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.10.7
botocore==1.13.7
certifi==2019.9.11
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
docutils==0.15.2
gensim==3.8.1
idna==2.8
jmespath==0.9.4
joblib==0.14.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.1.1
pandas==0.25.2
pyparsing==2.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
s3transfer==0.2.1
scikit-learn==0.21.3
seaborn==0.9.0
six==1.12.0
sklearn==0.0
smart-open==1.8.4
tqdm==4.37.0
urllib3==1.25.6

Can anyone help me for this I did R&D over sites but not found exact solution.

Comment: You seem to have attached a screen shot of your Dockerfile instead of the actual file.  Can you replace this with its actual contents?  Is Flask actually included in your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong Flask version it should be **Flask==1.1.1** and try.